# How to set the UISegmentControl as selected and multiple touches for selected index?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I have one problem :I have UISegmentedControl with three indexes 0,1,2. when i select the index of UISegmentedControl it is working fine but I need to have multiple touches and it should be focued How it can be achieved. how can be programed for Tapping the selected index again and it should work...

```
     NSArray *segmentTextContent = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: allString, favoritesString,filterString, nil];
segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segmentTextContent];
[segmentedControl setFrame:CGRectMake(60,10,200,30)];
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
//segmentedControl.momentary = YES;

segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.tintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:36/255.0 green:61/255.0 blue:103/255.0 alpha:1];
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex =0;
[toolBar1 addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

Comment: a little confusing... please try again?

Comment: selected one is Focued and calling declared actions and working properly and again I tap on the same button it should call again

Comment: Is there any idea or way to have multiple events for UISegmentedControl

Answer (score 0):

```
mySegmentedControl.momentary = YES;
```

I believe this is want you want.